# How to segue to a new UIViewController at the end of an array count

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, segue

Let me first explain the concept. I ask the user 3 questions, which are stored in an `NSArray`. There is one `UITextField` which the user will use to write all 3 answers to the questions.

What I would like to happen, when all three questions have shown from the array, the next time the user presses the Next `UIButton`, it segues to a new `UIViewController`. I have created the segue in main.storyboard and given it an identifier of countdownSegue.

When I run my app, and I get to the last question and press the Next button, the app just crashes and the error is "fatal error: Array index out of range" - which I don't understand why. My code is below to show what is happening with my questions array and with my button when it's pressed. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
let questions = ["Where are you going?", "Which city?", "When do you go?"]

var currentQuestionIndex = 0

let placeholder = ["Country", "City", "Date"]

var currentPlaceholderIndex = 0

@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Initial setup on button press
    questionTextField.hidden = false
    barImage.hidden = false
    questionTextField.placeholder = placeholder[currentPlaceholderIndex]
    questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    questionTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // Reset text field to have no text
    questionTextField.text = ""

    // Displays the questions in array and displays the placeholder text in the textfield
    if currentQuestionIndex < questions.count && currentPlaceholderIndex < placeholder.count {

        currentQuestionIndex++
        currentPlaceholderIndex++
        buttonLabel.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    } else if currentQuestionIndex > questions.count && currentPlaceholderIndex > placeholder.count {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("countdownSegue", sender: self)

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your `index` against `count - 1` because index is zero-based.

```
if currentQuestionIndex < questions.count - 1 && currentPlaceholderIndex < placeholder.count - 1{
    currentQuestionIndex++
    currentPlaceholderIndex++
    buttonLabel.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
} else {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("countdownSegue", sender: self)
}
```

**EDIT:**

You didn't check the index when getting values from your array to display text. It overflows when you tap NEXT button on the last question.

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Initial setup on button press
    questionTextField.hidden = false
    barImage.hidden = false
    questionTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // Reset text field to have no text
    questionTextField.text = ""

    // Displays the questions in array and displays the placeholder text in the textfield
    if currentQuestionIndex < questions.count && currentPlaceholderIndex < placeholder.count {
        questionTextField.placeholder = placeholder[currentPlaceholderIndex]
        questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

        currentQuestionIndex++
        currentPlaceholderIndex++
        buttonLabel.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("countdownSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this has made the segue work, but it happens on displaying the last question, rather than after the last question has been displayed. does that make sense? thanks

Comment: I have tried this but it just makes the app crash again like it used to. I tired it also with adding the - 1 after the .count, but the segue still happens too early. thanks

Comment: Did it crash in this function or somewhere else? It's hard to tell without knowing the logic of the rest of the app. And your question is actually nothing to do with initiate a segue. It's purely about array index out of range.

Comment: It crashes and the logs still say "fatal error: Array index out of range", and in the code, it highlights this line: questionTextField.placeholder = placeholder[currentPlaceholderIndex] and says: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: I checked your code... you are using `<=` instead `<` in your code. Please read my code carefully.

Comment: It must have been when i was experimenting with different ways! Thanks for all your help with this Richard. Much appreciated.